# How to share text from page on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a page with several sections with facebook and twitter button. Every section is text only. I am trying to make a share of sections, not page.

I tried this code like this, from the internet, but it shares a whole page.

```
<script>
document.getElementById('shareBtn').onclick = function() {
  FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    display: 'popup',
    href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
  }, function(response){});
}
</script>
```

Comment: _“I am trying to make a share of sections, not page”_ - that’s not possible - you can only share _URLs_. If you want to be able to share X individual pieces of content, then you also need X individual URLs for those, that return the correct set of Open Graph meta tags for each. (With just one single URL, at most you could suggest a _quote_ to the user via the share dialog parameter - but they will be able to remove that, if they don’t like it.)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. I also thought that was not possible because I never saw it before.  Is it possible to make assign URLs to every section? I know I can give them IDs but IDs are not appearing on my link.

Comment: No, the hash part of the URL is a purely client-side construct, that does not even get send to the server. You need actually distinctive URLs (for example via different GET parameters, `page.php?share=section1`, ...), and those need to at least return the relevant OG meta data. They don’t need to contain any actual content besides that, you can just put a bit of JS code in there that redirects human visitors […]

Comment: […] who might be following those links from Facebook back to the “main” page (and maybe even specific section, by “translating” that passed parameter value `section1` back into `#section1` at that time.) But you also got to be aware that this will split the counts of like/shares/reactions between those URLs, they will not count for your “main” URL any more.